# Mysql Mariadb query returning nonetype when field is 0

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

FIXED: Bottumn of post shows the fix

Portion of a pipeline I am working on querys a mariadb table and grabs the value and adds that to a another value from another portion of the script. Then a second query is made to update that field the value was grabbed from. The table and column in question default value is set to 0 so I cannot find out why it is returning as nonetype. It does not happen to all queries. This script is running multiple processes/threads using joblib and majority of the queries work. It is in a try/except and continues to run after the iteration.
Command Line output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
(1,)
<class 'tuple'>
(1,)
<class 'tuple'>
(10,)
<class 'tuple'>
(5,)
<class 'tuple'>
(2,)
<class 'tuple'>
(2,)
<class 'NoneType'>
None
ERROR:  wallstreetbets_04-02-2021.csv  : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable  TICKER:  (4, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 0, 0), 'CME')
("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable",)
```

Code:

```
def runCountFinder(File):
    try:
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='****', password='****', host='localhost', database='DataSAIL')
        myCursor = cnx.cursor()

        # print("Reading CSV ", File )
        dataDF = pd.read_csv(r'/home/****/myoptane/Trawler/Dataframes/%s' % File, names=["Timestamp", "Subreddit", "Post/Comment"])


        # print("Concatenating data ", File)
        data = ''.join(map(str, dataDF['Post/Comment']))


        # print("RUNNING FIND COUNTS ", File, flush=True)
        result = findCounts.process_bodies(data)

        result = findCounts.filter_pos_tokens(result, findCounts.target_pos_tags)

        result = findCounts.count_tickers(result, findCounts.tickers)

        # print("COMPLETED", flush=True)

        # print("TRANSFERRING TICKER COUNTS TO DATAFRAME", File, flush=True)
        resultDF = pd.DataFrame(list(result.items()), columns=['Ticker', 'Count'])

        # print("COMPLETED", flush=True)

        # resultDF.to_csv(r'D:\Git\lewisuDataSAIL\Dataframes\testing.csv', index=False)



        # print("SAVING VALUES TO LISTS ", File, flush=True)
        tickerList = resultDF['Ticker'].tolist()
        countList = resultDF['Count'].tolist()

        row_count = len(tickerList)
        # dateList = dataDF['Timestamp'].tolist()
        #
        #
        # dateFix = dateList[1]
        #
        # print(dateFix, " ", File)

        dateFix = File.split("_", 1)[1]
        dateFix = dateFix.split(".", 1)[0]
        dateFix = dateFix + " 00:00:00"
        dateFix = datetime.strptime(dateFix, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")


        # if len(str(dateList[1])) == 10:
        #     dateFix = datetime.strptime(dateList[1], "%m/%d/%Y")
        # else:
        #     date_slice = dateList[1]
        #     date_slice = date_slice[0:10]
        #     dateFix = datetime.strptime(date_slice, "%Y-%m-%d")
        # print(" dateFix COMPLETED ", dateFix, flush=True)

        for i in range(0, row_count):
            try:
                sql1 = "SELECT mentions FROM Trawler WHERE date = %s AND stock = %s"
                val1 = (dateFix, tickerList[i])
                myCursor.execute(sql1, val1)
                dbMentionCount = myCursor.fetchone()
                # print(tickerList[i])
                print(type(dbMentionCount))
                print(dbMentionCount)


                newCount = countList[i] + dbMentionCount[0]
                # print(newCount)
                # try:
                #     # print("count(%d) + dbcount(%d)" % (countList[i], dbMentionCount[0]))
                #     newCount = countList[i] + dbMentionCount[0]
                # except Exception:
                #     print("Failed to add counts ", File)
                #     continue
                sql = "Update Trawler SET mentions = %s WHERE date = %s AND stock = %s"
                val = (newCount, dateFix, tickerList[i])
                myCursor.execute(sql, val)
                cnx.commit()
                # print("ROW UPDATED # %d" % i)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error: ", e, " Info: ", val, " count: ", countList[i], " dbcount: ", dbMentionCount[0])

        cnx.close()
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print("%s Completed***** in %0.4f seconds" % (File, (toc - tic)), flush=True)


    except Exception as e:

        print("ERROR: ", File, " :",e, " TICKER: ", val)
        print(e.args)
```

Updated CL ouput with raise exception:

```
<class 'tuple'>
(0,)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0), 'CLOU')
<class 'tuple'>
(0,)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0), 'CME')
<class 'tuple'>
(0,)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0), 'CODX')
<class 'tuple'>
(0,)
(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0), 'COIN')
<class 'NoneType'>
None
ERROR:  stocks_03-23-2021.csv  : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable  TICKER:  (4, datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 0, 0), 'CODX')
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in runCountFinder
    newCount = countList[i] + dbMentionCount[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 600, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "main.py", line 116, in runCountFinder
    print("Error: ", e, " Info: ", val, " count: ", countList[i], " dbcount: ", dbMentionCount[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 142, in <module>
    print(parallel([delayed(runCountFinder)(file) for file in fileList]), flush=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1016, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 908, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 554, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Snipit from database table:

```
| 87482641 | 2021-03-14 00:00:00 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 |        0 | CODX  |        2 |
| 87473610 | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 | 000000000000014.0000 | 000000000000014.3000 | 000000000000013.5600 | 000000000000013.7200 |   766080 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473601 | 2021-03-16 00:00:00 | 000000000000013.7300 | 000000000000014.0000 | 000000000000013.1100 | 000000000000013.4600 |   513404 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473592 | 2021-03-17 00:00:00 | 000000000000013.3700 | 000000000000013.8800 | 000000000000012.6700 | 000000000000013.6000 |   623469 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473583 | 2021-03-18 00:00:00 | 000000000000013.5000 | 000000000000014.5000 | 000000000000013.4100 | 000000000000013.6900 |   813095 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473574 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | 000000000000013.8500 | 000000000000014.1595 | 000000000000013.4000 | 000000000000014.0500 |   795922 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87482635 | 2021-03-20 00:00:00 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 |        0 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87482633 | 2021-03-21 00:00:00 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 |        0 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473565 | 2021-03-22 00:00:00 | 000000000000014.0500 | 000000000000014.9700 | 000000000000014.0250 | 000000000000014.5300 |   840116 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473556 | 2021-03-23 00:00:00 | 000000000000014.6600 | 000000000000014.6728 | 000000000000013.4400 | 000000000000013.6100 |   766312 | CODX  |        4 |
| 87473547 | 2021-03-24 00:00:00 | 000000000000013.8100 | 000000000000013.9100 | 000000000000012.3400 | 000000000000012.4000 |   912711 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473538 | 2021-03-25 00:00:00 | 000000000000012.1648 | 000000000000012.6420 | 000000000000011.8000 | 000000000000012.1200 |  1650841 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87473529 | 2021-03-26 00:00:00 | 000000000000011.1100 | 000000000000011.1300 | 000000000000009.5700 | 000000000000009.7000 |  3822083 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87482627 | 2021-03-27 00:00:00 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 |        0 | CODX  |        0 |
| 87482621 | 2021-03-28 00:00:00 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 | 000000000000000.0000 |        0 | CODX  |        0 |
```

So the problem was indeed there not being a row that matched the passed in values, but what was throwing me off was the error message I had printed was showing the wrong information. The error message for some reason I will look into shows the next iteration of values instead of the values where the error was raised. After realizing that I checked to the values the error was actually raised on and found the row to be missing. For those interested. those rows are missing because of the portion of script that populates the table grabs ticker information for a ticker, and for those tickers, they have not been on the NASDAQ for very long so there is now rows made for those dates.

Comment: Your exception handling is hiding the error traceback. Add a `raise` to the `except` block to see it.

Comment: For the last set of inputs you have passed to your query, there is no data in your `Trawler` table.

Comment: The default value just determines what gets stored during an INSERT query if you omit the field.  If your query returns no results, you get None.  That's what is happening here.

Comment: @TimRoberts The database gets populated elsewhere, I can look directly into the database and see that values are 0. It should return 0 in the query, it does for thousands of other values except about 5% of others. I can look directly at the row the field values are "4, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 0, 0), 'CME'" and the mentions field value is 0

Comment: Look, the problem you're seeing is NOT that the FIELD is returning None.  That would print a tuple with `(None,)`.  In this case, it's that the row does not exist.  The query has failed.  You need to `print(val1)` so you can double check that you're fetching the row you think you are.

Comment: @TimRoberts Okay, I understand that part, its not the field that is returning nonetype it is the query. But it should not be returning nonetype, The values that are being passed in var1 are count, timestamp and ticker which are printed in the error message: 4, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 0, 0), 'CME'. I can use those values and search the table and find a row that matches that.

Comment: @KlausD. I added to the post showing the raised exception from the CL output

Comment: You showed "CODX".  The record that doesn't exist is "COIN".

Comment: @TimRoberts This is running on a tickerlist of 4500, I reran the script and grabbed new output that showed raise. The raise exception that is showed was the first time the problem occured. This problem occurs several times over the 4500 tickers for multiple dates. I will update post to show entires for COIN as welll

Comment: @TimRoberts I found my problem, will updated post

Comment: `fetchone()` will return `None` after all rows have been fetched. You have to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was indeed there not being a row that matched the passed in values, but what was throwing me off was the error message I had printed was showing the wrong information. The error message for some reason I will look into shows the next iteration of values instead of the values where the error was raised. After realizing that I checked to the values the error was actually raised on and found the row to be missing. For those interested. those rows are missing because of the portion of script that populates the table grabs ticker information for a ticker, and for those tickers, they have not been on the NASDAQ for very long so there is now rows made for those dates.